# How to write a function that returns the combined output of several built-in functions

Tags: output-formatting, symbolic, scoping

I am trying to make a module that takes a Boolean function, and prints the following:

- the function's truth table
- the function's NOR epxression
- the function's minimal Disjunctive normal form

So far I have the following:

```
Module[{f}, f[x_, y_] := Input["Enter Boolean function"]; 
Print[BooleanTable[f[x_, y_], {x_, y_}]]; 
Print[BooleanConvert[f[x_, y_], NOR]]; 
Print[BooleanMinimize[f[x_, y_]]]]
```

However, for every `Print` I need to reenter the Boolean function. How do I make every expression to use the same Boolean function without having to re-enter it three times?

Answer (score 2):

```
booleanTable := Module[
  {var, iter},
  f = Input["Enter Boolean function"];
  var = BooleanVariables@f;
  iter = Sequence @@
    ({#, {True, False}} & /@
      var);
  Column[{Table[
        Evaluate[{var, f} // Flatten],
        Evaluate[iter]] //
       Flatten[#, Length[var] - 1] & //
         Prepend[#, {var, f} // Flatten] & //
     Grid[#, Frame -> All] &,
    Row[{
      "\nNOR expression: ",
      BooleanConvert[f, "NOR"]}],
    Row[{
      "\nMinimal-length disjunctive normal form: ",
      BooleanMinimize@f}]
    }]]

booleanTable
```

[image]